# Как из 4 байтного числа сделать одного BigInteger

Tags: java

Суть задачи такая, я кодирую байты файла, 1 байт исходного файла = 4 байтам зашифрованного.
К примеру, закодированный байт равен 3125890409. В байтовом представлении это [186, 81, 77, 105]. Для расшифровки я должен этот массив представить в одним числом
Как я могу эти 4 числа сначала перевести в двоичную систему, а затем в десятичную и присвоить BigIntger?
Я думал сделать вот так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileData2.length; i+=4) {
    BigInteger message = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i]);
    BigInteger message2 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 1]);
    BigInteger message3 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 2]);
    BigInteger message4 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 3]);
}
```

И дальше переводить каждое в двоичное, но выглядит слишком сложно, и что если нужно будет сделать не 4 байтное, а 8 байтное и выше. Как можно реализовать попроще?

Comment: А вам точно нужно использовать `BigInteger`?  Стандартное целое число имеет те же 32 бита = 4 байта, просто в вашем примере число 0xBA514D69 "станет" отрицательным -1,169,076,887.

Comment: Да, использовать надо BigInt, так как числа могут быть больше 4 байт, если поменять это в условии. И сейчас даже на 4 байтах получаются отрицательные числа, почему так?

Comment: Потому что диапазон целых чисел в джаве `[-2^31, 2^31 - 1]`, и все числа, у которых в старшем бите установлена 1, обрабатываются как отрицательные в дополнительном коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Как я могу эти 4 числа сначала перевести в двоичную систему, а затем в десятичную и присвоить `BigInteger`*

В `BigInteger` есть [соответствующий конструктор](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int,int)), принимающий на вход массив байт, смещение и размер, так что представленный код можно переписать так:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < fileData2.length; i += 4) {
    BigInteger message = new BigInteger(fileData2, i, 4);
    // ...
}
```

Однако, следует отметить, что полученное таким образом число из показанного примера будет выводиться как отрицательное:

```java
byte[] fileData2 = new byte[] {
    (byte) 186, (byte) 81, (byte) 77, (byte) 105
};        
        
for (int i = 0; i < fileData2.length; i += 4) {
    BigInteger message = new BigInteger(fileData2, i, 4);
    // ...
    System.out.println("bigint: " + message + "; long: " + message.longValue() + "; int: " +  message.intValue());
}
```

```
bigint: -1169076887; long: -1169076887; int: -1169076887
```

---

Если *очень* необходимо вывести указанное число как положительное, понадобится использовать буфер на пять байтов, где старший байт всегда будет хранить 0.  Тогда можно будет копировать в этот буфер фрагменты по 4 байта при помощи [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) и создавать `BigInteger` при помощи стандартного конструктора:

```java
byte[] buf = new byte[5];
for (int i = 0; i < fileData2.length; i += 4) {
    // скопировать 4 байта из fileData2 с позиции i в буфер buf с позиции 1 
    // чтобы пропустить 1 байт
    System.arraycopy(fileData2, i, buf, 1, 4);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf));
    BigInteger message = new BigInteger(buf);
    // ...
    System.out.println("bigint: " + message + "; long: " + message.longValue() + "; int: " +  message.intValue());
}
```

```
[0, -70, 81, 77, 105]
bigint: 3125890409; long: 3125890409; int: -1169076887
```