# Почему не правильно складываются байты

Tags: java

Суть задания такая, я зашифровываю большое число в 4 байта. Для того чтобы расшифровать это большое число и соединить в одно я использую данную функцию:

```
    decrypt = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i]); //150

    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        decrypt = BigInteger.valueOf((decrypt.intValue() << 8) | fileData2[i + j]);
    }
```

То есть например, мое зашифрованное число выглядит в байтовом представлении файла так:
[150,15,38,10] я должен перевести весь этот массив в десятичный вид и получить такое число 2517575178. Но почему то такой цикл работает через раз, и получил число -1777392118, в чем проблема? Почему так, как можно исправить?

Comment: `2517575178` больше чем `2^31 - 1` - максимальное значение `int`. Оно не может быть представлено в переменной типа `int`. Переполнение приводит к величине `2517575178 - 2^32 = -1777392118`. Её вы и видите. Замените `intValue` на `longValue` и получите `2517575178`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как из 4 байтного числа сделать одного BigInteger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463198/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-4-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-biginteger)